# eclipse JFrame pages are closed

Tags: java, eclipse

When I close to "Gelir Ekleme Alanı" then the main page close too. What am I doing for avoid this problem. It is my school homework and I must solve the problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqILN.jpg)

Comment: Please take some time to read the help pages, especially the sections ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please share your code. Without seeing anything how can we ever try to solve your problem?

Comment: I agree with those above me that your question is bad written but I hope I could help you anyways.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you are in your JFrame saying something like

> GelirEklemeAlanıFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

which makes the JFrame execute

> System.exit(0);

when you press the red X which closes your whole application. But as you just want to close the window you have to change it to

> GelirEklemeAlanıFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

which just closes this frame or create a custom exitListener. If you want to make a custom exitListener to add some extra behaviors on exit, just look up on the internet for "exitListener in java swing" or JFrame.

Hope I helped you :) Good luck in school!